# How to unit-test a deserialization function used in serde(deserialize_with)?

Tags: unit-testing, rust, serde

I have a struct which implements `Deserialize` and uses the `serde(deserialize_with)` on a field:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct Record {
    name: String,
    #[serde(deserialize_with = "deserialize_numeric_bool")]
    is_active: bool,
}
```

The implementation of `deserialize_numeric_bool` deserializes a string "0" or "1" to the corresponding boolean value:

```rust
pub fn deserialize_numeric_bool<'de, D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<bool, D::Error>
    where D: Deserializer<'de>
{
    struct NumericBoolVisitor;

    impl<'de> Visitor<'de> for NumericBoolVisitor {
        type Value = bool;

        fn expecting(&self, formatter: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
            formatter.write_str("either 0 or 1")
        }

        fn visit_u64<E>(self, value: u64) -> Result<bool, E>
            where E: DeserializeError
        {
            match value {
                0 => Ok(false),
                1 => Ok(true),
                _ => Err(E::custom(format!("invalid bool: {}", value))),
            }
        }
    }

    deserializer.deserialize_u64(NumericBoolVisitor)
}
```

(I appreciate comments about code improvements)

I'd like to write unit tests for deserialization functions like `deserialize_numeric_bool`. Of course, my friendly search box revealed the `serde_test` crate and a [documentation page about unit-testing](https://serde.rs/unit-testing.html).
But these resources couldn't help me in my case, as the crate tests a structure directly implementing `Deserialize`.

One idea I had was to create a newtype which only contains the output of my deserialize functions and test it with it. But this looks like a unnecessary indirection to me.

```rust
#[derive(Deserialize)]
NumericBool {
    #[serde(deserialize_with = "deserialize_numeric_bool")]
    value: bool
};
```

How do I write idiomatic tests for it?

Comment: I don't know enough about idiomatic Serde to properly answer this, but you can instantiate a `Deserializer` implementation via a crate like [`serde-json`](https://docs.serde.rs/serde_json/struct.Deserializer.html), which would then give you something you could pass in to the function. If using a JSON crate in your tests feels weird, you could use something like [`serde-value`](http://arcnmx.github.io/serde-value/serde_value/struct.ValueDeserializer.html).

Comment: Did you find a more direct solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've come across this question several times while trying to solve a similar problem recently. For future readers, pixunil's answer is nice, straightforward, and works well. However, I'd like to provide a solution using [serde_test](https://docs.serde.rs/serde_test/) as the [unit testing](https://serde.rs/unit-testing.html) documentation mentions.

I researched how [serde_test](https://docs.serde.rs/serde_test/) is used across a few crates that I found via its reverse dependencies on [lib.rs](https://lib.rs/). Several of them define small structs or enums for testing deserialization or serialization as you mentioned in your original post. I suppose doing so is idiomatic when testing would be too verbose otherwise.

Here's a few examples; this is a non-exhaustive list:

- [Example](https://github.com/time-rs/time/blob/a50cf684cb80980e50ce088e9c65e0ffd530e4ba/tests/integration/serde/timestamps.rs) from [time](https://github.com/time-rs/time)
- [Another example](https://github.com/time-rs/time/blob/33bfe5cfe383eb28f11fc56ba14aad541e895705/tests/integration/serde/rfc2822.rs) from [time](https://github.com/time-rs/time)
- [Example](https://github.com/tokio-rs/slab/blob/afef8287061b732b9cfcfd0ab841c215e83675e2/tests/serde.rs) from [slab (tokio)](https://github.com/tokio-rs/slab)
- [Example](https://github.com/rust-bitcoin/bitcoin_hashes/blob/5e33d88578a98d79a9ebb50563bd4e471e1aee58/src/sha512.rs) from [bitcoin_hashes](https://github.com/rust-bitcoin/bitcoin_hashes)
- [Example](https://github.com/uuid-rs/uuid/blob/f1d19d4b5d8b1182d95b85e0fd6d30cdbc18fb4d/src/external/serde_support.rs) from [uuid](https://github.com/uuid-rs/uuid)
- [Example](https://github.com/servo/euclid/blob/82656b97f6658b0040a1a358033e1bec918cd599/src/length.rs) from [euclid](https://github.com/servo/euclid)

Anyway, let's say I have a function to **deserialize a `bool` from a `u8`** and another function that **serializes a `bool` to a `u8`.**

```rust
use serde::{
    de::{Error as DeError, Unexpected},
    Deserialize, Deserializer, Serialize, Serializer,
};

fn bool_from_int<'de, D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<bool, D::Error>
where
    D: Deserializer<'de>,
{
    match u8::deserialize(deserializer)? {
        0 => Ok(false),
        1 => Ok(true),
        wrong => Err(DeError::invalid_value(
            Unexpected::Unsigned(wrong.into()),
            &"zero or one",
        )),
    }
}

#[inline]
fn bool_to_int<S>(a_bool: &bool, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
where
    S: Serializer,
{
    if *a_bool {
        serializer.serialize_u8(1)
    } else {
        serializer.serialize_u8(0)
    }
}
```

I can test those functions by defining a `struct` in my `test` module. This allows constraining the tests to those functions specifically instead of ser/deserializing a larger object.

```rust
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::{bool_from_int, bool_to_int};
    use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
    use serde_test::{assert_de_tokens_error, assert_tokens, Token};

    #[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Deserialize, Serialize)]
    #[serde(transparent)]
    struct BoolTest {
        #[serde(deserialize_with = "bool_from_int", serialize_with = "bool_to_int")]
        a_bool: bool,
    }

    const TEST_TRUE: BoolTest = BoolTest { a_bool: true };
    const TEST_FALSE: BoolTest = BoolTest { a_bool: false };

    #[test]
    fn test_true() {
        assert_tokens(&TEST_TRUE, &[Token::U8(1)])
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_false() {
        assert_tokens(&TEST_FALSE, &[Token::U8(0)])
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_de_error() {
        assert_de_tokens_error::<BoolTest>(
            &[Token::U8(14)],
            "invalid value: integer `14`, expected zero or one",
        )
    }
}
```

`BoolTest` is within the `tests` module which is gated by `#[cfg(test)]` as per usual. This means that `BoolTest` is only compiled for tests rather than adding bloat. I'm not a Rust expert, but I think this is a good alternative if a programmer wishes to use `serde_test` as a harness.

Answer (score 5):

My current solution uses only structures already provided by `serde`.
In my use case, I only wanted to test that a given string will deserialize successfully into a bool or has a certain error. The [`serde::de::value`](https://docs.serde.rs/serde/de/value/index.html) provides simple deserializers for fundamental data types, for example [`U64Deserializer`](https://docs.serde.rs/serde/de/value/struct.U64Deserializer.html) which holds a `u64`. It also has an [`Error` **struct**](https://docs.serde.rs/serde/de/value/struct.Error.html) which provides a minimal representation for the Error traits – ready to be used for mocking errors.

My tests [look currently like that](https://github.com/pixunil/gtfs-sim/blob/28ac73d34ee05a9ec766def7ed004bb9658df79b/import/src/utils/deserialize.rs#L125-L148): I mock the input with a deserializer and pass it to my function under test. I like that I don't need an indirection there and that I have no additional dependencies. It is not as nice as the `assert_tokens*` provided `serde_test`, as it needs the error struct and feels less polished. But for my case, where only a single value is deserialized, it fulfills my needs.

```rust
use serde::de::IntoDeserializer;
use serde::de::value::{U64Deserializer, StrDeserializer, Error as ValueError};

#[test]
fn test_numeric_true() {
    let deserializer: U64Deserializer<ValueError> = 1u64.into_deserializer();
    assert_eq!(numeric_bool(deserializer), Ok(true));
}

#[test]
fn test_numeric_false() {
    let deserializer: U64Deserializer<ValueError> = 0u64.into_deserializer();
    assert_eq!(numeric_bool(deserializer), Ok(false));
}

#[test]
fn test_numeric_invalid_number() {
    let deserializer: U64Deserializer<ValueError> = 2u64.into_deserializer();
    let error = numeric_bool(deserializer).unwrap_err();
    assert_eq!(error.description(), "invalid bool: 2");
}

#[test]
fn test_numeric_empty() {
    let deserializer: StrDeserializer<ValueError> = "".into_deserializer();
    let error = numeric_bool(deserializer).unwrap_err();
    assert_eq!(error.description(), "invalid type: string \"\", expected either 0 or 1");
}
```

I hope that it helps other folks too or inspire other people to find a more polished version.

Answer (score 2):

`serde_test` can't be used to test your function directly because `serde_test` does not expose the `Deserializer` it uses internally. Consequentially, `serde_test` can only be used to test `Serialize` and `Deserialize` implementations, and can't be used for testing functions meant to be used with `deserialize_with`.

However, you can do this with the [`serde_assert`](https://crates.io/crates/serde_assert) crate (disclaimer: I wrote `serde_assert`). `serde_assert` does expose a `Deserializer` to be used directly in tests, which makes it very simple to directly test your function:

```rust
use serde_assert::{de, Deserializer, Token, Tokens};

#[test]
fn test_numeric_true() {
    let mut deserializer = Deserializer::builder()
        .tokens(Tokens(vec![Token::U64(1)]))
        .build();

    assert_eq!(deserialize_numeric_bool(&mut deserializer), Ok(true),);
}

#[test]
fn test_numeric_false() {
    let mut deserializer = Deserializer::builder()
        .tokens(Tokens(vec![Token::U64(0)]))
        .build();

    assert_eq!(deserialize_numeric_bool(&mut deserializer), Ok(false),);
}

#[test]
fn test_numeric_invalid_value() {
    let mut deserializer = Deserializer::builder()
        .tokens(Tokens(vec![Token::U64(2)]))
        .build();

    assert_eq!(
        deserialize_numeric_bool(&mut deserializer),
        Err(de::Error::Custom("invalid bool: 2".to_owned())),
    );
}

#[test]
fn test_numeric_invalid_type() {
    let mut deserializer = Deserializer::builder()
        .tokens(Tokens(vec![Token::Str("".to_owned())]))
        .build();

    assert_eq!(
        deserialize_numeric_bool(&mut deserializer),
        Err(de::Error::InvalidType(
            "string \"\"".to_owned(),
            "either 0 or 1".to_owned()
        )),
    );
}
```